# grails -Dgrails.env=test war not work

Tags: grails-3.3

- Java: Oracle JDK 1.8
- Grails: 3.3.1

I create an empty grails application and execute below command:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=test war
```

At the end of output lines, it appears:

```
| Built application to build\libs using environment: production
```

Well, I thought it should have appeared as below:

```
| Built application to build\libs using environment: test
```

I also tried

```
grails -Dgrails.env=TEST war
```

Same result.

But if I tried

```
grails test war
```

It appears

```
| Built application to build\libs using environment: test
```

Where is the porblem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the root cause is powershell.
If I execute the command line "grails -Dgrails.env=test war" in CMD window, the result displays

```
| Built application to build\libs using environment: test
```

However, if I execute the same command in PowerShell window, the result is wrong because PowerShell will see "-Dgrails.env" as "Dgrails". So in PowerShell in Windows 8/10, I have to change the command as below:

```
grails -D"grails.env"=test war
```

Then the result will be correct